# Laravel Echo listenForWhisper not work with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native

I'm running **websockets:serve** in Laravel App. Private channels work perfectly, and messaging I have built for it works. Now I'm trying to get the whisper to work for the typing status as well but no luck.

Sending whisper:

```
Echo.private('chat').whisper('typing', 'data string');
```

Listen whisper:

```
Echo.private('chat').listenForWhisper('typing', callback);
```

In my console, when i'm typing message:

```
0: connection id 737029829.558252983 received message: {"event":"client-typing","data":"data string","channel":"private-Chat"}.
```

channels.php:

```
Broadcast::channel('Chat', function ($user) {
    return $user;
});
```

But callback function is not called inside listenForWhisper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is working. I had to set **'enable_client_messages' => true** in **\config\websockets.php**